# Can a control of dynamic strings like this be written in XAML?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

**Edit** - I revised the original text in an effort to better convey my actual question.

---

I'm interested in implementing a control like this in a WPF application. Basically it's a collection of strings - you can click in the blank area, and type a new string, and enter will commit a new item to the list. You can click the 'x' button to remove an item.

The screenshot below is from a website, but I have to imagine I could accomplish the same in WPF. It seems like it might be accomplished with a styled listbox, mabye?

The biggest problem I've had is that when I try to look this up, I don't even know what a control like this would be named, so researching has been a non-starter. I'm frustrated by my inability to begin researching this due to a lack of ideas as to *what* to search for.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Looks like a card view to me. Many grids can switch to a view like that.  (I use the exceed grid and it can do a card view like that. (Out of curiosity, what site did you see that on?). http://stackoverflow.com/a/554972/16241

Comment: I don't know if there's an existing control for it, but I'm sure you could do something simiar with an `ItemsControl` templated to use a `WrapPanel` for items and with a custom `ItemsPanelTemplate`. And perhaps customized to add a `TextBox` with no borders at the very end for text input.

Comment: It's a ListBox or ItemsControl with WrapPanel for the ItemsPanel. ItemsSource would be bound to an ObservableCollection of `Color`, `String`, Int32 (ARGB quad is 32 bits), or whatever floats your boat. Then you give ItemTemplate a DataTemplate that displays the things as colors, and some minor fiddling for the delete buttons (which are a Button with a ControlTemplate that displays a very simple Path). No custom control needed. Write it as a Style for reuse.

Comment: That looks like a Card View. Many "for pay" control suites have them. Here is a stack overflow answer on how to turn a list view into a card view: http://stackoverflow.com/a/554972/16241

Comment: Oh I was thinking for the final TextBox item, you don't even need anything custom. Just have the bound item contain something like `IsNewItem=True`, and use a DataTrigger to draw the template for that item using a borderless TextBox. Then OnChange of the text, can change it to a proper item and add another new one at the end :)

Comment: @Vaccano - Wow, I never would have guessed "card view", thanks!That screenshot is from the settings page on a [Discourse forum](http://www.discourse.org/) I run at work.

Comment: I think is is pretty close to this but just use a WrapPanel  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got curious about this, so did a quick proof of concept of one way to get it done.

[image]

I used an `ItemsControl` bound to a collection of items.

The `ItemsPanelTemplate` is a `WrapPanel`, and the `ItemTemplate` is a custom template. There is also a `DataTrigger` to change the Template of the last item to be a borderless `TextBox` for text entry.

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox IsHitTestVisible="False" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" /> <!-- For Border -->
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Values}" Margin="4">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
                    <ContentControl.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="4" Padding="4">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeString}" />
                                        </Border>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Value}" Value="0">
                                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <TextBox Text="{Binding SomeString}" BorderThickness="0" Padding="5" Width="50" />
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </ContentControl.Style>
                </ContentControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

It should be pretty easy to take something like this and add extra functionality :

- `ItemTemplate` can be updated to look like what you have. I am guessing an `IValueConverter` is used to convert the Text value into a `Color` for the bar along the bottom
- X button on the `ItemTemplate` can be bound to an `ICommand` to remove an item from the list, and can bind the current object as the `CommandParameter` to know which item to remove.
- A PropertyChange notification can be used when TextBox is changed to signal that it should flip a switch to make the last item in the list a "saved" item, and add another "new" item for the TextBox binding.

Overall, shouldn't be too hard to achieve what you're looking for.

And this is one of the reasons why I love working with WPF! Can make almost any control I want with ease. :D